# Streaming consecutive images received from Kinect's RGB camera on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, streaming, kinect

I'm gathering consecutive images from Kinect's RGB camera from the code below;

```
        PlanarImage Image = e.ImageFrame.Image;
        video.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
            Image.Width, Image.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, Image.Bits, Image.Width * Image.BytesPerPixel);
```

And i want to stream the series of images that i get from Kinect as a real time stream on my WPF application, but I don't know how to. The reason is that i want to be able to use the Kinect as a webcam, but the other solutions (coding a directshow filter, or using only one available one) didn't worked for me for resolution or my lack of knowledge in C++ issues. Writing a direct show filter for Kinect to act as a virtual cam is extremely challenging for someone on my level with C++.

To sum up, problem lies within the output of Kinect, it gives me a series of images which i don't really know how to turn it to a real time stream that I can display from other applications.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF a commercial library is an option take a look at http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk-net2.html - it can capture and also stream in WMV...

Another commercial option would be Leadtools Videostreaming SDK - see http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/video-streaming.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But i can encode and stream a video on my hdd or webcam with the Expression Encoder SDK, if only Kinect would give me a video stream.. The problem is that it gives me consecutive images for every frame, and i don't know how to turn it into a real time stream and stream it. Checked the libraries but couldn't really found out what I'm looking for, will look for more, thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the libraries support your scenario - for example from the first link `JPEG/MJPEG, MPEG-4 and H.264 HTTP / RTSP IP cameras, HD cams supported` - IMHO the JPEG case is exactly your scenario, to make sure you can mail them...

Comment: Thanks, I've already sent the both SDK providers some e-mails related to my situation. Seeing these commercial products and the similarity between kinect and IP cameras. I'm also searching for cheaper commercial libraries, and sending e-mails like crazy, I spouse there is no better choice..

Answer (score 2):

DirectShow is indeed your best bet.  There is nothing in WPF for streaming video to other apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can stream the video with the Expression Encoder SDK as another choice but the problem lies with the Kinect's output. It doesn't give me a video stream, it gives me a series of planar images and i don't know how to stream it in realtime. Writing a DirectShow filter for Kinect to act as a virtual cam is just extremely hard, thus i'm trying to find an alternative. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above the Kinect produces a series of Images instead of generating a streaming video.

This page is going to be helpful while extracting depth data from the Kinect in Microsoft Kinect SDK:

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/hardware/2714-getting-started-with-microsoft-kinect-sdk-depth.html

If you are using processing you can import the SimpleOpenNI library(https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) which supports video capture (you can find examples within the library).

This video stream comes in .ONI format, which can be converted into AVI via the following library:
http://kirilllykov.github.io/blog/2013/03/19/convert-openni-star-dot-oni-files-into-avi/

All the best, let us know if you find any other method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Its been a while since I've worked on that project and well, we had to postpone the development due to some visa issues :(. [I've used this temporarily](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ee6e7ca-123d-4838-82b6-e5816bf6529c/can-now-use-kinect-camera-with-skype?forum=kinectsdk) for the job, I don't think it'll work with the new sdk. But I'll definitely look into your answer for self satisfaction, cheers!